# Hyrule Warriors Season Pass Not Working

Tags: hyrule-warriors

The new Hyrule Warriors DLC has been released and I have the season pass downloaded but it's not showing up in my game!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new DLC should already be downloaded. You can't open the game from the **Quick Start** menu.  The game must be opened from the **Wii U main menu** to install the new content.